Hall's Theorem Proof
I have always thought that the proof of Hall's Marriage Theorem is very straightforward. This is my proof idea. Let $G$ be a finite graph with bipartite sets $X$ and $Y$. Suppose that $X$ satisfies the marriage condition, and we want to prove that there is a perfect matching for $X$.
Let's arrange the vertices in $X$ in some arbitrary order, say it is $x_1, x_2,x_3,...x_n$. By the marriage condition, $x_1$ has at least 1 neighbor in $Y$, let it be $y_1$. We match $x_1$ to $y_1$. Now, the set $\{x_1,x_2\}$ should have at least 2 neighbors in $Y$. Even if one of these happened to be $y_1$, we are still left with at least one vertex, and we match $x_2$ to that vertex in $Y$, say it is $y_2$. Now, the set $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ should have at least 3 neighbors in $Y$. Even if two of them happened to be $y_1$, $y_2$, we are still left with at least one vertex, and we can match $x_3$ to that vertex. We continue this process and eventually every vertex in $X$ will be matched, and we have a perfect matching for $X$.
Is there anything wrong with this proof? I have seen this theorem on different textbooks and they all use proofs that are way more complicated than this one. For instance, GTM173 Graph Theory used an augmenting path technique that just seems very complicated.

This proof is not correct. At each stage we know that the set $\{x_1,\ldots,x_r\}$ has at least $r$ neighbours in $Y$, at most $r-1$ of which are already matched. But there is no reason why the remaining vertex should be adjacent to $x_r$, and so we may need to go back and change some of the previous matchings to be able to use it. (Essentially this is what an augmenting path approach does.)
In other words, the greedy algorithm is not guaranteed to find a maximal matching.
